# Use def or val in Chisle to define some "const-macro" value?

Tags: chisel

I want to define some constants in Chisel and have them produce an effect similar to macro expansion in C, replacing them at compile time where they are used. Should I use val or def for this purpose?

```scala
// which one should I use?
def DATA_WIDTH = 32 
val DATA_WIDTH = 32

val reg = Reg(Vec(CPUConfig.DATA_WIDTH, UInt(CPUConfig.DATA_WIDTH.W)))
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You should generally use a `val` for a constant value. `def` means that the expressions is always re-evaluated when you use it (like a function call). This does not make a difference for your simple `Int` value though. `val` is thus preferable.